# How to adjust the font size and width of 'tabularx'?

Tags: tables, tabularx

Here is my code, some variable names are quite long:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X}   

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|b|b|s|s|s|s|s|s|s|}
    \hline
     aaaa aaaaa aaaaa & djfh &  aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{total}\\
    \hline
    - & - & - & - & kih & 1111 & 111 & 111 & 111 \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaa\_bbb & aaaaaaaaaaaaaa & 0 & 00 & - & - & - & - & - \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaa & 0 & 1111 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000& 0.000000 \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaaa aa & aaaaaaaaaa & 0    & 1111 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000& 0.000000 \\
     \hline
\end{tabularx}
 \end{table}
```

The table currently looks like this: The right side of the table is also a bit weird, it appears some extra length out of the last line, is there a way I can fix that? Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: How, in your opinion, is TeX supposed to line-break "words" such as `aaaaaaa\_bbb` and `aaaaaaaaaaaaaa`?

Comment: A separate issue: you are not using the `\hsize` machinery properly: The sum of the `\hsize`s must equal the number of columns of type `X`. But `2*0.9+7*0.8=7.4`, not `9`.

Comment: Denoting x and y the coefficients of `\hsize` for `b` and `s`, you have to solve the linear system 8x=9y, 2b+7s  = 9. An approximate solution is s=0.97, b=1.105.

Comment: or more simply do not use b and s at all, and use X for all the columns.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, now it looks better, but do you mind telling me how to adjust the font size as the length of some variables are too long.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mind showing me an example?

Comment: It's very simple: just after `\begin{table}`, and before `\begin{tabularx}`, use the font switching command `\small` , or `\footnotesize` (don't make it too small, it has to remain readable). If you need space, you also can play with the value of `\tabcolsep` (6 pt by default).

Comment: @Cecilia as there appears to be no linebreaking in these cells, I wouldn't use `tabularx` I'd just use tabular and `l` columns most likely, then use `\small` or `\footnotesize` if needed to make things fit.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried  'tabular' but the table is too long and the right side of the table disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no linebreaking I wouldn't use `tabularx` also you did not provide an example document so we do not know the page size, but in a standard `article` document this needs to be `\tiny` to fit, which is only just readable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\hd[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{b}{>{\hsize=0.9\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X}   

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|b|b|s|s|s|s|s|s|s|}
    \hline
     aaaa aaaaa aaaaa & djfh &  aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaa & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{total}\\
    \hline
    - & - & - & - & kih & 1111 & 111 & 111 & 111 \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaa\_bbb & aaaaaaaaaaaaaa & 0 & 00 & - & - & - & - & - \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaa & 0 & 1111 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000& 0.000000 \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaaa aa & aaaaaaaaaa & 0    & 1111 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000& 0.000000 \\
     \hline
\end{tabularx}
 \end{table}

\noindent X\dotfill text text\dotfill X

\begin{table}[htbp]
\tiny
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|*{9}{l|}@{}}
    \hline
     \hd{|c|}{aaaa\\ aaaaa\\ aaaaa} & djfh & \hd{c|}{aaaaaaa\\ aaaaaaaa\\ aaaaaa} & \hd{c|}{aaaaaaaaaa\\ aaaaaaaaa} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{total}\\
    \hline
    - & - & - & - & kih & 1111 & 111 & 111 & 111 \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaa\_bbb & aaaaaaaaaaaaaa & 0 & 00 & - & - & - & - & - \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaaaaa & aaaaaaaaaa & 0 & 1111 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000& 0.000000 \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaaa aa & aaaaaaaaaa & 0    & 1111 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000 & 0.000000& 0.000000 \\
     \hline
\end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

In practice I would remove all the horizontal and vertical lines, which do not improve readability.

Comment: Hi, it's a report '\documentclass{report}'

Comment: @Cecilia OK thanks for specifying. that is the same page size as `article` so the above comments apply. (next time please post a complete document in the question:-)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works!